# Create a template for RollingRandomAccessFile in log4j2?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

Is it possible to wrap the definition of a `RollingRandomAccessFile` logger in a template?

Eg: I want to reuse the following definition multiple times, with only the "myname" string changing according to the logger name:

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="myname" fileName="same/path/sameprefix-myname.log"
                         filePattern="same/path/archive/same-prefix-myname.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="mypattern" charset="UTF-8" />

    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1G"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

If I need multiple loggers with each having a different name (and logfile name), I'd have to copy the above definition all over again. Which seems boilerplate if I always just change a simple string in it.

Comment: You misunderstood. I'm not searching for a way to generally replace the `myname` variable. I'm looking for a templating mechanism so I don't have to copypaste the full `RollingRandomAccessFile` code above over and over again for each logger defined.